# The running time of different machine?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I have written a function that sorts a big scale of data. To test its performance, I compared it with `qsort`. If I compile it on my desktop which is running FreeBSD with GCC 4.2.2, the result is that `qsort` taking less time than my function. However, I compiled it on a server which is running RedHat with GCC 4.1.2, the result is that my function takes less time than `qsort`.

I am confused about whether my function is better than `qsort` or not. Could someone help me explain this strange situation?

I have tested it a lot of times using the same CFLAGS,  running it in same machine and all the other same conditions except the different functions.

My code:

```
 53 int
 54 main(void)
 55 {
 56     int * array_first, * array_next;
 57     int len = 1000000;
 58     int i;
 59     struct timeval start, duration;
 60 
 61 
 62 
 63     array_first = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
 64     array_next = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
 65 
 66 
 67     for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
 68         *(array_first + i) = rand() % 1000;
 69         *(array_next + i) = *(array_first + i);
 70     }
 71 
 72     set_starttime(&start);
 73     quicksort(array_first, len, sizeof(int), compar);
 74     get_runningtime(start, &duration);
 75     printf("%lu\n", duration.tv_sec * MICRO_PER_SEC + duration.tv_usec);
 76     set_starttime(&start);
 77     qsort(array_next, len, sizeof(int), compar);
 78     get_runningtime(start, &duration);
 79     printf("%lu\n", duration.tv_sec * MICRO_PER_SEC + duration.tv_usec);
 80 
 81     assert(memcmp(array_first, array_next, sizeof(int) * len) == 0);
 82 
 83     free(array_first);
 84     free(array_next);
 85 
 86     return 0;
 87 }
 88
```

Comment: There is not a single, universal implementation of `qsort`. Did you use the same test set on both machines? Where they inactive apart from your test programs? Did you run the programs 11 times, averaging over the last ten runs?

Comment: Different hardware, different OS, different architecture, different compiler versions. All these can contribute in varying ways and to varying amounts.

Comment: Be aware that the qsort() function might not implement the quicksort algorithm.

Comment: How different are the times between each method? How much do the times vary between multiple test runs? Do the times vary if you call `srand()` so your test data is different each test run?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, about twenty times(is it too few?), and mostly same result as my question. I add `srand()` and test, same result.

Comment: How significant is the time difference? 50%, 10%, 0.001%?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, 18% at 10 million data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many many reasons why the performances are different.

- Implementation of `qsort` could be different in the two systems, one happens to suite your test-case better
- If test-cases are generated randomly, you could have just got unlucky with one test case
- Compiling your code with different compiler versions, means different optimizations are done that change the performance of your code
- Running the tests on different systems means that there would be different performances in the same code. On one architecture with a certain test-case, the cache may be marginally misused, while on another architecture with bigger cache this is not issue.

I could think of a 100 hundred other reasons, but this should be enough to let you know you shouldn't try making such a comparison.

Comment: See my updated question.To avoid the difference, I ran it in the same environment.

Comment: Based on your update, you say you have run it over an over with the same machine, right? What happens now? Do you see sometimes `qsort` is better and sometimes your own function? If that is the case, then that shows that `qsort` works better on certain ordering of input while yours works better on another. This is quite typical in sorting algorithms

Comment: I make a addtion test, If there is a lot of same data, `qsort` is better, but if they are mostly random, mine is better.

Comment: @MYMNeo, congratulations. I think you can be happy with your sort.

Comment: the new problem is that with a lot of same data, it takes lots of times but `qsort` not.Tick your answer for your comment with patience

Comment: @MYMNeo, well this means that the implementation of `qsort` (which in fact probably is not quick sort) has a best-case in sorted data (or at least equal data). This means that when it sees a large amount of equal data, it quickly understands it. For example, insertion sort is `O(n)` given sorted input, and indeed it is good practice to use insertion sort even inside quick sort when the size of array is smaller than a certain number, such as 5~6.

Comment: If you are implementing quick sort, there are a lot of good implementations online that you could learn from, or compare your code to. It could be for example that you swap in case of `<=` instead of `<` which means extra swaps in case of equality or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you made sure to use the same data on both computers, and made sure no other programs running at the same time skewed your testing results.

First, you could have a look at the generated assembly code, and check whether both compiler versions generate the same output.

If they do, the difference is probably caused by a different hardware architecture of the two computers, mainly CPU and its caches.

One implementation might be faster if run on a CPU with a large L2/L3 cache, but way slower if there is less space available.

Comment: See my updated question.To avoid the differences, I ran it in the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your compar() function can be inlined (static functions can be inlined), that would be a big win. The amount of inlining depends very much on the compiler, and flags.

For qsort(), inlining cannot be used: qsort depends on the call-back function being a true function. Normally, the compare function will show up eating xx% of the CPU in a profile, even for cheap compare functions(when the call overhead is relatively large). (have you profiled?)